# how to configure access db file in app.config file?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

i use access 2010 with my c# project i link to database file in all my forms using         `OleDbConnection db_con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\projecty bashi nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\db_file.accdb");` know i want to configure OleDbConnection in my app.config file to work in all machines without need to change the db file link?

Answer (score 0):

you can add it in app.config like this

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\projecty bashi nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\db_file.accdb" name="connectionString"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and use it like this

```
string conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();
db_con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
```

Comment: thank you  @No One ... when i use ur code it gives me this error `A field initializer can not reference the non-static field,mehtod, or property'Bashi_Nawxoyy.login.conString'` ... and how i write |DataDirectory| for my link?

Comment: show the complete code you are using. my code won't give exception

Comment: string conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();
        OleDbConnection db_con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
        private void login_bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbCommand ol_com = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            ol_com.Connection = db_con;
                db_con.Open();
                if (user_txt.Text != "" && pass_txt.Text != "")
                {//here my login code}
        }` error image link http://s14.postimg.org/8jgjqjoa9/Capture.png .....

Comment: move your creation of objection inside the method and always use your connection within using block. like using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conString)){}

Comment: ok thank you know the error is solved ... i want to put |DataDirectory| for my link to work in another machines??

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your question

Comment: istead of using <connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\projecty bashi nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\db_file.accdb" name="connectionString"/>
</connectionStrings> .... i want to use  <connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Data Source=|DataDirectory|/db_file.accdb" name="connectionString"/>
</connectionStrings> ... put my application and my db file in the same folder

Comment: i mean i want to create setup file for my project and i want the setup file can connect to db file if i install setup file in any machine ... how can i do this ...?

Comment: you want to keep db at a centeral location or on each clients machine?

Comment: i want my exe file can connect to db file when i run the exe file in any machine(work in any machine not one mchaine with my path) ... i don't understand your mean by central location or each clients machine? i mean attach db file with exe file?

Comment: no i mean that when you install your application, will your database be copied to each client's machine?

Comment: ya i want to be copied to each client's machine when i install exe file and it can connect to database file ... know my exe file not copy db file to clients machine

Comment: you need to add your database file to your setup project and you can deploy it then to each client.

Comment: http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.in/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html follow this

Comment: this article do not help me exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The connection string which specified was correct.

In `app.config`:

```
<add connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
     Data Source=complete path of accdb" name="Connectionstring"/>
```

And you will call it in C# as:

```
OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection();

dbConnection.ConnectionString =
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

//  This You Can Use as a connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
                       <add connectionString="Data Source=Test;D:\projecty bashi nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\db_file.accdb Catalog=Demo; User ID=sa; Password=Password" name="DemoConnection" providerName="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" />
```

```
// And You can use this in constructor of the class file as bellow
 string connStringKey = "DemoConnection";
          connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connStringKey].ToString();
```